# align to right text of label (inline-block)

Tags: forms, size, alignment, css

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6L6ZL
is possible align to right the text of label **without specify WIDTH** size?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
fieldset {
display: inline-block;
}

fieldset input{
float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <p><label>First Name</label><input type="text" /></p>
    <p><label>Second Name</label><input type="text" /></p>
    <p><label>Address</label><input type="text" /></p>
    <p><label>Age</label><input type="text" /></p>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align:right;` to the `<p>` element.